# Select a template specialization by enum values for static polimorphism

Tags: templates, c++03, crtp

Here is simplified sample of  problem, featuring CRTP:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

enum  ActionTypes {
    eInit      = 2 << 0,
    eUpdate    = 2 << 1,
    eMultUpdate = 2 << 2
};

template <class Data, 
          unsigned  Actions = eInit|eUpdate|eMultUpdate>
class ActionData
{
    template<ActionTypes As /*???*/>
    struct action {
        static void exec(Data*) { std::cout << "ActionData:: /*dummy*/ exec()\n"; };
        static void exec(Data*,int) { std::cout << "ActionData::/*dummy*/ exec(int)\n"; };
    };

    template<>
    struct action < /*???*/ > 
    {
        static void exec(Data*) { /*...*/ };
    };

    template<>
    struct action < /*???*/ >
    {
        static void exec(Data*, int) {  /*...*/  };
    };

    Data* derived() { return static_cast<Data*>(this); }
protected:
    void init()          { action<eInit>::exec(derived()); }
    void update()        { action<eUpdate>::exec(derived()); }
    void update(int key) { action<eMultUpdate>::exec(derived()); }
public:
    enum Keys { DEFAULT_KEY = -1 };

    void call(ActionTypes a, int key = DEFAULT_KEY)
    {
        switch (a) {
        case eInit:
            init(); break;
        case eUpdate:
            if (key == DEFAULT_KEY)
                update();
            else
        case eMultUpdate:
                update(key);
        }
    }

};

class Test : public ActionData<Test, eUpdate>
{
public:
    void update() { std::cout << "Test :: update()\n";  }
};


int main()
{
    Test actor;
    ActionTypes a = eInit;
    actor.call(a, 0); // useless here but must be possible.
    actor.call(eUpdate, 0);
    actor.call(eUpdate);
}
```

Essentially not all derived classes may implement all handlers, a enum is used to declare that and a dummy version of handler must be called. The problem is that it's not possible to select any implementation but default one using `enum` and `enable_if` alone, it requires a non-type parameter, which stupefied me.

*PS. Another problem is target platform is limited to C++98\C++03 or tr1 C++11 (no variadic templates). The awkward interface is a legacy of dynamic (but not used as such) polymorphic architecture using function pointers in a big C (not C++!) project. Necessity of pointers or vtable made system unstable to  programmer errors leading to vtable being  overwritten.*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that I should use a partial specialization for all cases including where there is no match:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

enum  ActionTypes {
    eInit      = 2 << 0,
    eUpdate    = 2 << 1,
    eMultUpdate = 2 << 2
};

template <class Data, 
          unsigned  Actions = eInit|eUpdate|eMultUpdate>
class ActionData
{
    // Never gets selected
    template<ActionTypes A, typename Enable = void > struct action {};

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action<A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == 0>::type >
    {
        static void exec(Data*) { std::cout << "ActionData:: /*dummy*/ exec()\n"; };
        static void exec(Data*,int) { std::cout << "ActionData::/*dummy*/ exec(int)\n"; };
    };

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action < A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == eInit>::type  >
    {
        static void exec(Data* o) { o->Data::init(); };
    };

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action < A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == eUpdate>::type  >
    {
        static void exec(Data* o) { o->Data::update(); };
    };

    template< ActionTypes A >
    struct action  <  A, typename std::enable_if<(A & Actions) == eMultUpdate>::type >
    {
        static void exec(Data* o, int key) { o->Data::update(key); };
    };

    Data* derived() { return static_cast<Data*>(this); }
protected:
    void init()          { action<eInit>::exec(derived()); }
    void update()        { action<eUpdate>::exec(derived()); }
    void update(int key) { action<eMultUpdate>::exec(derived(), key); }
public:
    enum Keys { DEFAULT_KEY };

    void call(ActionTypes a, int key = DEFAULT_KEY)
    {
        switch (a) {
        case eInit:
            init(); break;
        case eUpdate:
            if (key == DEFAULT_KEY) {
                update();
                break;
            } else {
        case eMultUpdate:
                update(key);
                break;
            };
        }
    }

};

class Test : public ActionData<Test, eUpdate>
{
public:
    void update() { std::cout << "Test :: update()\n";  }
};


int main()
{
    Test actor;
    ActionTypes a = eInit;

    actor.call(a, 0);
    actor.call(eUpdate);
    actor.call(eMultUpdate, 0);
}
```